# Responsive design using CSS media query

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have a div which has height 100% on regular pc screens. but for mobile screens, i wanted to not set the height as 100%. is there any way to remove the height: 100% that was set for regular screens using css media queries.

Comment: see the link http://pugetworks.com/blog/2011/04/css-media-queries-for-targeting-different-mobile-devices/...

Comment: i know how to use media queries. i just want to know about my question. height: xxxx for mobile devices. i just want to know this xxxx

Answer (score 1):

Like this `below` `links` `useful` for you.

**[demolink1](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-create-media-queries-in-responsive-web-design/)**

**[demolink2](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewport` in meta tag. It is for responsive web designing. i.e.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

[More information here.](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design)